# How to find top 2 distinct employee name with highest salary?

Tags: mysql, database

this is my table

```
select emp_no, salary
from salaries
order by salary desc
```

```
emp_no, salary
'43624', '158220'
'43624', '157821'
'47978', '155709'
'109334', '155377'
'109334', '155190'
'109334', '154888'
'109334', '154885'
'80823', '154459'
'43624', '153458'
'43624', '153166'
'47978', '151929'
'80823', '151768'
'109334', '151484'
'43624', '151115'
'46439', '150345'
```

i have used query

```
select distinct emp_no, salary
from salaries
order by salary desc
limit 2
```

but it is only returning top two salary of same user 
**i need emp_no of top two highest employees emp_no and their salary **

Answer (score 1):

You can use `subquery` and `max()` aggregation function.

```
select * from 
    (select emp_no, max(salary) maxsalary from salaries group by emp_no) t1 
order by t1.maxsalary desc
limit 2
```

Comment: I don't see the need for a subquery here. You can just aggregate and sort: `select emp_no, max(salary) max_salary 
    from salaries 
    group by emp_no 
    order by max_salary desc
    limit 2`

Comment: @GMB, yes we can do that. Please add your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the need for a subquery here. You can aggregate and sort directly:

```
select emp_no, max(salary) max_salary 
from salaries 
group by emp_no 
order by max_salary desc
limit 2
```